# Loading role-based navigation upon login

Tags: php, navigation

I have a login form through which one of three types of users gets into the website (PHP-based). Upon login the index page should load with the navigation bar based on user type. Right now the login page loads the index without checking for user type. How to achieve this?

I'm not using any PHP framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the login process, store the user's usertype into the session:

```
session_start();

// ...

// if the user's login was successful:
$_SESSION["user_type"] = 1; // or similar
```

then you can check on each subsequent page load what type the user is and include the relevant navigation bar:

```
session_start();

switch ($_SESSION["user_type"])
{
  case 1:
    // nav type 1
    break;

  default:
    // default navigation bar
    break;
}
```

Don't forget to call `session_start()` on each page you need this information, although I'm presuming you're doing that anyway since you have logged-in and non-logged-in users...!

Comment: Fantastic. I was sitting on this for a couple of days now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

either  1. A simple switch statement userType 
 switch(userType)
  {
    case 1:{ //do stuff break();}
etc

Or you could have named includes load particular include files based on role variable

e.g include_once({$userType}.php

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. I need to load the navigation in a background way - i.e., the difference should not be visible in the URI.

Comment: just for reference either of theset would not change url